# MSYS2 mingw-w64 gcc / c++ 32 and 64 bit

Tags: c++, windows, gcc

I have an executable that is always crashing and GDB gives me below staktrace -

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x00000000004013b5 in __tmainCRTStartup ()
#1  0x00000000004014e8 in mainCRTStartup ()
```

I am completely unable to understand the issue here - but looking at my CMAKE build file I found -

```
LINK_LIBRARIES = -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

I think it links 32 bits libraries - hence I assumed that we might need MinGW 32 bit. I was compiling with MinGW64 and the final executable is **PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows format**.

I referred to the [post](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/557/)  where they state -

```
Testing with MSYS2 mingw-w64 gcc:
32 bit: no crash
64 bit:
You're testing a Win32 build, while problem is with Win64
```

I am not sure how to compile using MSYS2 mingw-w64 gcc 32 or 64 bit - how should I setup my environment?

Is the post talking about 32 / 64 bit Windows OS or I am missing something?

Comment: The issue is very easy to understand: you have a bug in your code. That's it. Trying to find a magical combination of compilation flags that fixes the bug is a waste of time. Unfortunately, there is no "--fix-my-bugs" compilation option. The only way to do so is to find the bug, and fix it.

Comment: I have debuged the code until my code main function exits but the segmentation fault occurs after to that with stacktrace as corrupted.

Comment: Makes sense. Your code corrupts the stack at some point, and the corruption doesn't come to light until `main()` exits. I can trivially write some code that makes a bunch of recursive calls, with the inner one subtly corrupting the stack so that everything blows up long after the inner function returns, and is ancient history. Like I said, you won't find a compiler switch to fix the bug for you. You'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: But my code works and executes perfectly in Visual Studio - no crash no issues

Comment: Just because code produces expected results in one specific configuration does not mean that it's bug-free.